# Simple Bash script to check for hosts

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm currently trying make a tool in bash that will just check for alive systems. I don't need it to be some crazy complicated tool. I just need it to tell me my machines are up and running. I know my script is garbo... That's why I'm here.

```
#!/bin/bash

here()
{
ping -c 1 $1 > dev/null
echo "Good morning, Here are the machines that are up and running: $i"
}

for i in insert ip range
do here $i
done
```

Comment: Double-quote your variables when you use them

Comment: Why is `nmap` not acceptable? It implements the ping scan it seems like you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something similar to this should help, add as many IP as you want to the list of ips:

```
#!/bin/bash

ips=(192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 127.0.0.1)

here() {
    ping -c 1 $1 > /dev/null

    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
    then
        echo "Good morning, Here are the machines that are up and running: $i"
    fi

}

for i in ${ips[@]}

do here $i

done
```

Comment: Instead of individual variables, use an array: `ips=(192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 127.0.0.1 ...)` then loop with `for ip in "${ips[@]}"`- you're allowed to put newlines and other arbitrary whitespace inside the parentheses of the array declaration, so it can be extremely readable.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks updated the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Consider something with nmap?

```
nmap -sP 10.1.2.0/24 10.2.5.0/24
```

It may be even simpler than a ping-loop, and it can scan multiple hosts in parallel so it'll appear much faster; but it will require the installation of nmap and its usual dependencies, and that may upset a resident security Oberleutnant fixated on the worst-case.

update: okay, Oberleutnanten for sure.

Instead:

```
xargs parallel -j20 ping -c1 -- | grep 'bytes from'
```

like

```
echo 10.0.{1..2}.{1..15} |\
  xargs parallel -j20 ping -c1 -- | grep 'bytes from'

64 bytes from 10.0.2.15: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.016 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.150 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.176 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.138 ms
```

the time's good, too, as most of it is waiting for the pings to die at once.  The positive results come back super fast:

```
$ time (echo 10.0.{1..2}.{1..15} | xargs parallel -j30 ping -c1 -- | grep 'bytes from')
64 bytes from 10.0.2.15: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.016 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.150 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.176 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.138 ms

real    0m10.030s
user    0m0.019s
sys     0m0.018s
```

Swap out an arping and its particular parms for the ping if you wanna sniff winboxes too, as they hate pings.

Change out the cheesy grep for an awk '/bytes from/{print $4}' if you wanna get keen.

No bones about it, these other guys' ideas look like great quiz submissions and mine looks like banging nails with a screwdriver, but it's fast and simple.

Comment: Yeah I thought about nmap first but its a no go. I can use python or bash.

Comment: Curses.  Look into the parallel tool in the MoreUtils project to speed up the pings in parallel, then.  And if python is your jam, totally consider using it.

Answer (score 0):

How big is your IP range?

For a /24 consider

```
for i in {1..254} ; do
    if ping -c1 10.11.12.$i >/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; do
        echo "10.11.12.$i is up"
    else
        echo "10.11.12.$i is down
    fi
done
```

for a /16, you can add a second loop:

```
for j in {1..254} ; do
    for i in {1..254} ; do
        if ping -c1 10.11.$j.$i >/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; do
            echo "10.11.$j.$i is up"
        else
            echo "10.11.$j.$i is down
        fi
    done
done
```

And take a few cups of coffee waiting for it to finish.

But really `nmap` is the right tool.

Comment: I have 10 machines I need to make sure are up everyday. So it's by no means a big range.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are.

You can use like this:

`./your_script_name.sh 192.168.1.0/24`

```
#!/bin/bash

SUBNET=$1

if [[ -z "$SUBNET" ]]; then
    echo "Usage: ./your_script_name.sh <SUBNET>"
    exit
fi

printsubnet() {
        local OLDIFS="$IFS"
        local SUB=${1/\/*/}
        local MASK=$(( 1 << ( 32 - ${1/*\//} )))

        IFS="."
                set -- $SUB
                IPS=$((0x$(printf "%02x%02x%02x%02x\n" $1 $2 $3 $4)))
        IFS="$OLDIFS"

        for ((N=0; N<MASK; N++))
        {
                VAL=$((IPS|N))

                printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n"                  \
                        $(( (VAL >> 24) & 255 ))        \
                        $(( (VAL >> 16) & 255 ))        \
                        $(( (VAL >> 8 ) & 255 ))        \
                        $(( (VAL)       & 255 ))
        }
}

mapfile IPS < <(printsubnet $SUBNET)

for row in "${IPS[@]}";do
        ping -c 1 "$row" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "$row is up"
        else
                echo "$row is down"
        fi
done
```

Comment: You might want `mapfile -t` to strip the newlines

Comment: If you use `local IFS="."`, then you don't need to save the OLDIFS.

Comment: I don't recall where I read this, but `for ((...)) {...}` with the braces is not recommended: use `do...done`